# Angular eCrypt encryption return null

Tags: angularjs, eway

I am using eway payment gateway for my .Net application.I have installed eWay.Rapid package from NuGet Package Manager.
I am using client side encryption for encrypt card details.

This is my encrypt function:

```
var paymentDetails ={
                card_number: eCrypt.encryptValue(card_number),
                card_cvn: eCrypt.encryptValue(card_cvn)
             };
```

I have inserted this script after form tag in html.

```
<script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.min.js"></script>
```

Encrypt function always return `eCrypt:null`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue get resolved after i added client side encryption key in HTML form. Client Side Encryption key was provided by E-Way.